# Searching for TOD, ending up at Ecto

Tags: ros, object-recognition, ecto, tod-detecting, tod-training

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello ROS-users and developers,

I am getting a bit confused while searching for a possibly fresh and working version of TOD.

I guess these two are slightly old for me:

- http://www.ros.org/wiki/tod
- http://www.ros.org/wiki/textured_object_detection

These are said to be deprecated and unstable in different threads regarding this topic.

- http://www.ros.org/wiki/tod_training
- http://www.ros.org/wiki/tod_detecting

While all the above references:
http://www.ros.org/wiki/object_recognition which consists of

- http://www.ros.org/wiki/object_recognition_core
- http://www.ros.org/wiki/object_recognition_server
  which are one could say highly underdocumented :)
  There is no documentation on that page but there is a reference to http://ecto.willowgarage.com/recognition.

Digging into the docs here for object_recognition might help:
http://ecto.willowgarage.com/recognition/release/rc1/object_recognition/index.html

however I feel a bit confused now that I installed ros-electric-object_recognition which seems to include ecto and TOD related codes but have no idea how to start with it.
Ok the documentations are there but they are a bit outdated and not really convenient for me.

I would appreciate any help either if someone can help me

1. by naming which to work with of the above (or none right now and wait for the ecto release) or
2. assemble a simple training&run with TOD or
3. providing a link to an updated "how to run TOD (ecto) for newbies" tutorial

Thx in advance :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/29357/searching-for-tod,-ending-up-at-ecto/) by [Bence Magyar](https://answers.ros.org/users/1102/bence-magyar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 358 on 2012-03-08

Post score: 7

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Alireza](https://answers.ros.org/users/1637/alireza/) on 2012-03-10**:
It's exactly my question too!!!

**Comment by [Bence Magyar](https://answers.ros.org/users/1102/bence-magyar/) on 2012-03-12**:
notify me please if you manage to find something out :)

**Comment by [Julius](https://answers.ros.org/users/252/julius/) on 2012-04-15**:
I'm curious, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, please follow the updated documentation on : http://ecto.willowgarage.com/recognition/

Just jump to the ROS quickguide if you can't wait :)

If you find any bug (in the code or the documentation), please file a bug report at the links indicated at http://www.ros.org/wiki/object_recognition/

A lot of infrastructure/build work had to be done before advertising the stack but we're finally done. We're actively developing/using it for more/better pipelines.

---

Originally posted by [Vincent Rabaud](https://answers.ros.org/users/358/vincent-rabaud/) with karma: 1111 on 2012-04-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try look at http://answers.ros.org/question/32015/running-ecto-object-recognition-on-ubuntu-1110-ros. While I hope that someone finds a less complicated way to install ECTO object recognition on ROS Electric / Ubuntu 11.10 in my question, I also show how to track a template and how to run the capturing preview (although I do not guarantee that installation works the same on your system).

---

Originally posted by [Julius](https://answers.ros.org/users/252/julius/) with karma: 960 on 2012-04-17

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1